# how to open pdf file from sdcard in android without intent

Tags: android-intent

*please give me any answer for this question*

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/abc.pdf";
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
    intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that u r using pdfviewer library

```
try {
            // select a document and get bytes
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/" + "file.pdf");
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
            FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.NEW(channel.map(
                    FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size()));
            raf.close();
            // create a pdf doc
            PDFFile pdf = new PDFFile(bb);
            // Get the first page from the pdf doc
            PDFPage PDFpage = pdf.getPage(1, true);
            // create a scaling value according to the WebView Width
            final float scale = ViewSize / PDFpage.getWidth() * 0.95f;
            // convert the page into a bitmap with a scaling value
            Bitmap page = PDFpage.getImage(
                    (int) (PDFpage.getWidth() * scale),
                    (int) (PDFpage.getHeight() * scale), null, true, true);
            // save the bitmap to a byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            page.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            stream.close();
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            // convert the byte array to a base64 string
            String base64 = Base64
                    .encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            bp.add(base64);
            // create the html + add the first image to the html
            // String html =
            // "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body bgcolor=\"#7f7f7f\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"
            // + base64 + "\" hspace=10 vspace=10><br>";
            // loop through the rest of the pages and repeat the
            // above
            for (int i = 2; i <= pdf.getNumPages(); i++) {
                PDFpage = pdf.getPage(i, true);
                page = PDFpage.getImage((int) (PDFpage.getWidth() * scale),
                        (int) (PDFpage.getHeight() * scale), null, true,
                        true);
                stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                page.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                stream.close();
                byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                bp.add(base64);
                // html += "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + base64
                // + "\" hspace=10 vspace=10><br>";
            }
            // html += "</body></html>";
            // load the html in the webview
            // wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html",
            // "UTF-8",
            // "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("CounterA", e.toString());
        }
```

my above code contains two scenerio,

1. present code getting the pdf file and converting it to base 64 string and save it to bp( arraylist
2. The commented code is to show the input stream base 64 string in a web view,

   ```
           WebView webview = new WebView(activity);
   webview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body bgcolor=\"#7f7f7f\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"
           + imageArray.get(position) + "\" hspace=10 vspace=10><br>";
   html += "</body></html>";
   webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
   ```

this is the code that u can use to show in a webview.,

or else u can convert the base 64 string to image and u can use it.

- Don't forget to include

  ```
  PDFImage.sShowImages = true; // show images
  PDFPaint.s_doAntiAlias = true; // make text smooth
  HardReference.sKeepCaches = true; // save images in cache
  ```

if u r pdf file contains images.